# Executable jar file cannot find main

Tags: java, apache-poi, executable-jar

Ive seen many posts on this but i cannot find a solution to my specific problem. Ive checked the parameters of how i export the jar from eclipse and i am certain that the class containing  the main is checked as the main class (there is only one class in this project). The program runs fine in eclipse. 
I have used a bat file to try and run it as well, which reads (where EDT2 is the name of the jar):

```
 java -jar EDT2.jar
```

I have looked into the manifest file and it reads:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Sealed: true
 Main-Class: EDTCompiler2
```

The main of the file reads:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
```

The error and the command line invocation can be seen below:

http://s16.postimage.org/droox00sl/Untitled.png
[image]

Another unusual thing i see is that it gives an error for line 53, which is an object declaration type from an external library. I use the apache POI for excel with this program.

Comment: The error message says that you are calling a non-existing method on one of the library classes. Are you sure you are linking with the right version of the library?

Comment: I dont understand what youre asking. Ive never deployed software before so this is all new territory to me.

Comment: Where are you adding the library's class-path to the manifest?

Comment: You know that rather than post an image of the error message, it' a whole lot easier for you and us if you simply copy the text from your cmd window and post the text here. Just right click  your cmd window, click `select all` then press the enter key, and you've saved the text.

Comment: How do you copy from a windows terminal?

Comment: See edit to my comment above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not, i'm not actually even sure what that means or how to do that.

Comment: Did you package the correct depended jars into your EDT2.jar ? just verify it once by opening your EDT2.jar using 7zip or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edwin's diagnosis is correct: In the static initializer of your main class, you are loading another class, that fails loading. That throws the NoSuchMethodError and prevents your main class from loading. Hence the error message at the end. 
The missing method indicates that you are using different versions of the Apache POI library when you run your program in Eclipse, and when you run it on the commandline.

To fix this you have two options:

1. When you export your JAR from Eclipse, check the option that says "Extract required libraries into generated JAR". This should be selected by default, but does not seem to work for you right now.
2. Do not package the dependent libraries into the JAR, but add them to the classpath when you call java using the -cp option. With this option, you have to make sure to add the correct version of the libraries.

Comment: Isn't there a third option: add the class path of the dependent library to the manifest file?

Comment: Yep. But I never figured out how to do this properly, and from his comments it appears Nick is a beginner with this. So I thought to keep things simple.

Answer (score 1):

Your main class needs to be a fully qualified name.

In other words if `EDTCompiler2` is in the `package org.apache.whatever;` then your JAR file needs to specify a `Main-Class` of `org.apache.whatever.EDTCompiler2`.

Comment: The package name is just the default package.

Comment: If that is the case then he should get ClassNotFound exception. But here he is getting a NoSuchMethodError in the trace .

Comment: The line that is causing that error is:     public static Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

Comment: He is calling a static block in one of the classes that is running at load time.  This then throws an exception that the method in a class referenced in that block doesn't exist.  Perhaps that caused the class to not load, but still there isn't a loadable class at `EDTCompiler2`.  Odds are he's repacking his stuff (which can redetect old, nonremoved classes at their old package locations) or doing incremental compiles without really having the entire code tree brought up to date.